# Does a higher voltage always mean a higher electric field strength?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electrons, electric-current, voltage

In a step-up transformer, the output voltage is higher than the input voltage, while the output current is lower than the input current. Basically, since P = VI is conserved, the current has to decrease proportionately in the secondary coil if the voltage increases. But as we know that the voltage in the secondary coil is higher, does this mean that the electric field strength is also higher there? (Normally, when we increase the voltage by adding more cells in series, we are basically increasing the electric field strength that causes the current, right?)

If E is higher in the secondary coil, then shouldn't the electrons experience more drift velocity, and hence shouldn't the circuit produce more current?

Comment: Is the 9V ac peak or RMS?

Comment: @Farcher 9V RMS may be. Ignore the numbers to be honest, my question is simply what does a higher voltage in the secondary coil of a step-up transformer physically means. Just focus on the last 3-4 lines. Everything else was just to give a context.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your statement, *So now, the potential difference between the secondary coil of the step-up transformer is 9V, but this time, the current will decrease.*

$9\rm V$ ac RMS means that the average power dissipated over a cycle is the same as that dissipated when a $9\rm V$ dc supply is connected and so the RMS current should equal the dc current.

If it is a sinusoidal voltage variation then the instantaneous power varies from zero to being proportional to $(9\sqrt 2)^2 = 162$ where $9\sqrt 2$ is the peak voltage.
In terms of what is happening to the electrons and the electric fields inside the resistor they will suffer a variation equal to the frequency of the supply, sometime being zero and sometimes reaching a maximum value.

Comment: I think I've made a mess of the question. I've edited and simplified it now. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This an answer to the amended question.

You are mixing up two ideas here.
If the transformer is $100\%$ efficient then $V_{\rm primary}I_{\rm primary} =V_{\rm secondary}I_{\rm secondary}$.

If you keep the same value resistor connected to the secondary and increase the voltage across it, $V_{\rm secondary}'$, by increasing the primary voltage, $V_{\rm primary}'$, then the secondary current, $I_{\rm secondary}'$, will increase as $V_{\rm secondary}'=R\,I_{\rm secondary}'$.

This will result in the primary current,$I_{\rm primary}'$, increasing.

So now you will have more input power and more output power, ie $V_{\rm primary}' \,I_{\rm primary}'=V_{\rm secondary}' \,I_{\rm secondary}'$

Comment: That I understand. See, we are not changing the primary voltage or primary current. Since the number of turns in the secondary coil is more than that in the primary, the voltage in the secondary will be higher than the voltage in the primary, while the current in the secondary is proportionately lower than in the primary due to conservation of power. Now, what does this higher voltage across the secondary actually imply on physical terms? Does this mean that the electric field strength is also higher there?

Comment: It all depends what is connected to the secondary. If it nothing then there is no secondary current. If it is a resistor of fixed value then changing the secondary voltage will also change the secondary current.

Comment: Yes, there is a resistor connected to the secondary, and I'm talking about the voltage across it. Since the voltage across it is higher compared to primary, does this mean that the electric field strength is also higher there compared to what is in the primary?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser When a 1 cm long resistor is connected to the secondary, the voltage across it is high, thus the number of volts/cm (i.e. the field) is strong.   But, it is only higher field than if the same 1 cm long resistor were connected across the primary winding.   Those two different connections (and different conditions) apply in different points in space.   Electric fields aren't one-per-transformer scalars, they're varying-everywhere-in-space vectors.